# Suspicious relay address range in log

Tags: relays

I have a tor relay,and after few days i see many strings,like this

> http status 400 ("Suspicious relay address range -- please contact
>   us?") response from dirserver '171.25.193.9:443'. Please correct.

What is this and how can i change this?

Answer (score 2):

You or someone else has run malicious relays from your IP or IP range in the past, and you're blacklisted for it.

You should contact bad-relays@lists.torproject.org to find out more and see about resolving it.